# Normalized Power of a signal

Tags: signal-power, normalization

I have the following power values in Watts of a signal:

6.5e-8, 4.6e-8, 7.1e-8, 1.01e-7, 9.98e-7, 2.5e-6, 3.96e-6, 2.84e-5, 2e-4, 4.05e-4, 1.7e-6, 8e-7, 8.23e-8, 8.32e-8.

How do I normalize this to 1mW (0 dBm)?
Thanks.

Comment: Since these values are already in mW, they *are* normalized to 1 mW. Do you understand what "dBm" means? If not, a lecture of the wikipedia article on Decibel will be most enlightening, I guess!

Comment: thanks for the link, i am going through it now

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hi, are these values correct for normalization w.r.t 0dBm= -41.8, -43.37, -41.48, -40, -30.008, -26.02, -24.02, -15.46, -6.98, -3.92, -27.69, -30.96, -40.85, -40.8?

Comment: you say they are in mW. That's what **you** wrote. The conversion from mW to dBm is trivial, as said, see the wikipedia article on decibel.

Comment: I am sorry. The power values are in Watts. You were correct in pointing that out. I am editing my original question.

Comment: I wasn't pointing that out. How should I have known that? You question said mW. Doesn't matter. The conversion is still trivial! I really don't know where you're stuck with converting Watts to dBm. It's really not hard; can you explain where you're stuck, based on the definition of decibel and thus dBm?

Comment: Actually I am not stuck with the conversion. I guess from the definitions, what I previously did not know was that, normalizing to 1mW (0dBm) simply meant converting from Watts to dBm. If this conception is correct, then I am all set. So is understanding correct?
Also, will it be also dBm if I normalize my power values to an arbitray value (e.g. 5mW)?

Comment: "*normalizing to 1mW (0dBm) simply meant converting from Watts to dBm*" that is incorrect. Normalizing to 1 mW means converting it to mW. The conversion to dBm is something else. I'm not sure what you're tasked to do!